# How is that JSON.parse() is able to parse to JS Object without actually having the Object Propery defined in the JSON endpoint?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with the below code.

- I'm trying to reach a JSON file, and fetch some data.
- Pass it to render() function and convert to Javascript Object.

```
Promise.all(STATUS_CODES.map((status) => {
  const url = `https://${domainName}/api/v2/search/tickets?query="status:${status}"`;
  return client.request.get(url, options);
})).then((responses) => { render(responses); }) // [1] Function invoked here
  .catch((err) => { 
  showError('API request(s) failed.');
  console.error('API request(s) failed.', err);
});
}

function render(responses) {
  /** Convert JSON String into Javascript Object */
  const data = responses.map(r => JSON.parse(r.response)); // [2] Confused with this line
  const max = Math.max(...data.map(d => d.total));
```

The problem that I need help with is in this line

`const data = responses.map(r => JSON.parse(r.response));`

Here is some data that I fetch the JSON at `${status} = 2`: https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb535226

**Problem**

When [1] is invoked, and the JSON string is sent as a parameter to [2] to parse in JS Object. But, in the statement `r.response`, I expect there has to be a `response` property in the JSON. But I'm not able to find it if I manually search for it.

However in the next line `d.total`, I'm able to find `total` property.

**The Complete code works just as fine as expected, but I want to understand how does it work if `response` property is not there in the JSON String?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `client.request.get(url, options)` returns a `Promise` that resolves to an object which has a `.response` property. `responses` is an array of those *objects*, not an array of JSON strings.

In other words, each JSON response is wrapped inside another object, and accessing the `.response` property on one of those objects gives you access to the actual response data (which, here, is a JSON string).

The wrapper object (in your code, it's called `r`) may contain other data like the URL requested, or the status code of the response. The `.response` property is not part of the JSON - it's part of the `client.request.get` interface.

Comment: Plus, `JSON.parse` parses a String not an Object.